# How to Update Dataframe column in pyspark with conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to update one dataframe column based on some other column conditions. I have two columns in my dataframe  DATE_JOINING AND BONUS

```
df=spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(23-08-2021,''),(12-11-2009,''),(24-09-2013,'')

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['DATE_JOINING', 'BONUS'])
```

Basically IN SQL we can write query as

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE.SALARY
SET BONUS= 'GIVE BONUS'
where DATE_JOINING < 09-01-2015
```

In Pyspark i am trying below code

```
df=df.withColumn('SALARY',when(df.DATE_JOINING <'01-09-2018',"GIVE BONUS").otherwise(''))
```

But it is giving me data more year than 2018 year also which i dont want and not giving any result for Column less than 2018. How can i correct this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your date column is not actually of date type, but string type.
To perform operations on dates, you need to convert the column with [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html); furthermore, you must explicit dates through the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (df
 .withColumn('DATE_JOINING', F.to_date('DATE_JOINING', format='dd-mm-yyyy'))
 .withColumn('SALARY', F.when(F.col('DATE_JOINING') < '2018-09-01', 'GIVE BONUS').otherwise(''))
)

df.show()
+------------+-----+----------+
|DATE_JOINING|BONUS|    SALARY|
+------------+-----+----------+
|  2021-01-23|     |          |
|  2009-01-12|     |GIVE BONUS|
|  2013-01-24|     |GIVE BONUS|
+------------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: for c in ['DATEOFFIRSTCONTACT','APPLICATIONDATE']:
    df_7 = df_7.withColumn(
        c, 
        F.date_format(
            F.when(F.col(c).rlike('\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'), F.to_date(c, 'M/d/yyyy')),
            "dd-MM-yyyy"
        )
    )

Comment: this is the code i am using to convert it into date first

Comment: Try F.to_date(c, 'mm/dd/yyyy')

Comment: Text '2/1/2022' could not be parsed at index 0 -- Throwing this error